# Trouble with Pardot Tracking & Consent API and WordPress/CookieYes

Tags: pardot, cookies, tracking, wordpress

We are trying to get the Pardot tracking script to sync Account Engagement opt-in status to match our third-party consent manager without much luck. We are using the following for the website:

CMS: WordPress

Consent Manager Plugin: CookieYes

Here are the references we have been using to cobble together the script below, but the script doesn't seem to send any arguments in the GET request other than the piAId value.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/pardot/guide/tracking-and-consent-use-cases.html#syncing-account-engagement-opt-in-with-third-party-consent-management

https://www.cookieyes.com/documentation/implement-prior-consent-using-cookieyes/
(for split method to get the cookie consent string from CookieYes near the middle of the page.)

```
piAId = 'XXXXXX';
piCId = 'XXXXXX';
piDomain = 'info.mydomain.com';
(function() {
// The src value will now load pdt.js instead of pd.js
var s=document.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='//'+piDomain+'/pdt.js?aid='+piAId;
var c=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];c.parentNode.insertBefore(s,c);
// Initialize the queue
window['pdt'] = window['pdt'] || function(){(window['pdt'].cq = window['pdt'].cq || []).push(arguments);};
})();
function getCookie(key) {
const cookies = document.cookie
.split(";")
.reduce(
(ac, cv, i) =>
Object.assign(ac, { [cv.split("=")[0]]: cv.split("=")[1] }),
{}
)["cookieyes-consent"];
const { [key]: value } = cookies
.split(",")
.reduce(
(obj, pair) => (
(pair = pair.split(":")), (obj[pair[0]] = pair[1]), obj
),
{}
);
return value;
}
if (getCookie("consent") == "yes" && getCookie("analytics") == "yes") {
pdt('create', piAId, piCId, piDomain);
pdt('setOptIn', true);
pdt('sendPageView');    
}
if (getCookie("consent") == "no") {
pdt('create', piAId, piCId, piDomain);
pdt('setOptIn', false);
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks!